# Java - Apache POI - Read/Write .xlsx file - File getting corrupted and becomes empty

Tags: java, apache-poi, filereader, xlsx

I am using a Java program to read and write an existing .xlsx file(same file) but the file is getting corrupted, and the file size becomes zero bytes which is causing **"org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)”**.

One more thing is - this is not happening consistently. The program is reading and writing to file properly most of the time but occurring once out of 10-15 runs. It would be helpful if anyone has a solution to this. BTW, am using Apache POI 3.13.

Read File Program:

```
public String getExcelData(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum){
    String retVal = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Absolute/File/Path/Test-File.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        Row r = s.getRow(rowNum);
        Cell c = r.getCell(colNum);
        retVal=(c.getStringCellValue());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
```

Write File Program :

```
public void writeToExcel(String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum,String desc){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Absolute/File/Path/Test-File.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        Row r = s.getRow(rowNum);
        Cell c = r.createCell(cellNum);
        c.setCellValue(desc);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Absolute/File/Path/Test-File.xlsx");
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.peekFirst8Bytes(IOUtils.java:55)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:201)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
at ExcelLibrary.getExcelData(ExcelLibrary.java:139)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:82)
```

Comment: As far as I see your `public String getExcelData(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum)` is able to get *one* cells value from the given sheet, row and column. For this small task every time it creates a new Workbook from the stored file. Also the `public void writeToExcel(String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum,String desc)` every time creates a new Workbook from the stored file, writes *one* cells value into the given sheet, row and column and saves the whole Workbook. Why not having the Workbook open outside this methods and saving it only once if all cell values are set?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/12263649/2734784 for finding out how to close the xlsx properly

Answer (score 4):

You are reading and writing to the same file at the same time. Try to first close FileInputStream fis before writing to FileOutputStream fos. 
Or use temporary file to write new result and then rename it to original one.

BTW. close automatically performs flush, so it don't has to be called separately.

Comment: I have closed FileInputStream fis before writing to FileOutputStream fos and  excel was fine for almost 10 runs but later again same problem occurred and file became empty. Please let me know if any other solution to this problem, I am using OSX 10.9.5 with Microsoft Excel mac 2011.

Answer (score 3):

you need to close the FileInputStream and FileOutputStream  with org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos) and fis.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to your file, you seem not to be using [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()). Furthermore, your `close` code should be done in a `finally` block to ensure the stream is closed even if something wrong happens.

Answer (score 0):

As a java dev, you need to use `finally` block when you use `try-catch` block.
in your finally block, you must close `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.may be filehandler opened as you didn't close.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue initially, solution is simple.

I am writting only code line which u need to add **fis.close();
wb.close();** before returning **retval**

```
public String getExcelData(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum){
String retVal = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Absolute/File/Path/Test-File.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
    Row r = s.getRow(rowNum);
    Cell c = r.getCell(colNum);
    retVal=(c.getStringCellValue());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
fis.close();
wb.close();
return retVal;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out. I was facing the same issue but resolved it with below.

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(-Location-);
--- do whatever you want to do --
fis.close();
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(-Location-);
wb.write(fos);
fos.close();
wb.close();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).