# cant find close() method on Apache WorkbookFactory

Tags: java, apache-poi

i read about [Apache WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html)

the guide are saying to close workbook when done.
"Workbook should be closed after use"

but i dont have a close method to close it.

how could it be closed ?

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);
wb.close();
```

i'm working with Apache poi Maven, version 3.9

```
The method close() is undefined for the type Workbook   ...     line 423    Java Problem
```

Note 1: that in order to properly release resources the Workbook should be closed after use.

Note 2: also that loading from an InputStream requires more memory than loading from a File

i would like to use a file and not an input stream like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261014/close-filehandle-for-workbook-apache-poi) sayes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cant find close() method on Apache WorkbookFactory

You need to close the `Workbook`, not its factory.

> Note 1: that in order to properly release resources the Workbook should be closed after use.

Correct.

> Note 2: also that loading from an `InputStream` requires more memory than loading from a `File`

Untrue, unless the `InputStream` is a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: could you tell me how to close this Workbook ?

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);

Comment: InputStreams really do need more memory than files, [as explained here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), as with a File data can be left on disk and accessed as needed while with a Stream you have to buffer the whole lot into memory for the required random access

Answer (score 10):

`Workbook.close()` was implemented in poi 3.11 version.

You have to close your output stream after work with workbook is done and it was written.

From [POI user guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook):

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Don't forget to close workbook as well:

```
wb.close();
```

Comment: dont have this method. could you tell me how to close it ?

Comment: update your maven dependency version to <version>4.1.0</version>

Answer (score -1):

Please use new version of "Apache POI API Based On OPC and OOXML Schemas" Dependency because the close() method was implemented after the 3.11 version so if you use all the above version after 3.11 , the close() method will work for you.

For me, I have used this version of Apache POI dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```