# Is Apache poi write(outputstream) will close outputstream?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is Apache poi `workbook.write(outputstream);` will close outputstream?

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34283033/1160933

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cant find close() method on Apache WorkbookFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282946/cant-find-close-method-on-apache-workbookfactory)