# POI unable to save to same directory

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Just using workbook.write() more than once to the same directory, even with a random suffix gives the error below.  I am processing a ss through multiple steps and want to see each and retain the prefix of the filename.  Is this solved by OPC or POIFilesystem?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: directory cannot be null
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode.(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:66) ~[poi-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1407) ~[poi-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1374) ~[poi-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]

Comment: The directory mentioned in the error is the internally directory of the binary `OLE2` file system of the `*.xls` workbook. If that is `null`, then `POIDocument.close` must have be called. That sets the internally directory `null`. And: "Once `close()` has been called, no further operations should be called on the document.".

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you for the interesting detail it give insight.  Maybe bc I am calling workbook.close() that is happening.  The link below may be the reas
on and I will eliminate the workbook.close() and try later.  Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261014/close-filehandle-for-workbook-apache-poi